# Does build made on xcode 3.2 runs on IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, itunes

May be this will be silliest question but users are facing such problems.
Sorry for same.

I have made build on xcode 3.2 which has maximum IOS 4.3 and uploaded on itunes.

Now users which are downloading application having IOS 5.0 says that application is getting crashed or vanished.

So, just want to ask that build made on xcode 3.2 runs on IOS 5.0

Please help.....

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you have a bug in your app.

An app compiled for iOS 4.3 should work just fine. However, as with any update to the operating system, ambiguities in API calls are tightened, undocumented behaviours vanish and some APIs become deprecated. Deprecations won't cause problems (yet), though both of the others might.

For this reason you should be testing with new versions as they become available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested my application on xcode 4.2 i.e. IOS 5 .0 and found that there are no issues. Do I need to again upload my application?

Comment: You really need to test the build that's currently in the App Store on iOS5 since that's the version that people are reporting problems with. It's unlikely (though possible) that building with a new version of the SDK will fix a problem. Of course you can also look in iTunes Connect for the crash reports. I've fixed bugs that I've never seen that way.